# SpriteKit: Coloring the Background

Tags: swift, colors, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

i still try to learn Swift and SpriteKit and i have a new question.

So i am following this Tutorial/Video: [Noise Field](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjoM9oKOAKY&t=1628s)

My project now looks like this: [My Project](https://youtu.be/eNh6RPk297E)

I have 100 Particle Objects moving around and i want to blend some color of the particles to the white background. Inside the tutorial it is quiet easy. You just create the Background once, and inside the draw function (in SpriteKit this would be the update() function) you give your objects an alpha value like 0.1.

SpriteKit works quiet different. If i change the alpha value under draw my Particles are now almost hidden, but the color is not being "drawn" on the background.

I know this is because SpriteKit works different then the p5 library for javascript. But i wonder how i could get the same effect inside SpriteKit..

So inside the update function i have 2 loops, one for columns and one for rows. I have x columns and y rows - and for each "cell" i create a random CGVector. Now my Particles are moving around based on the CGVector of the cell which is the nearest to the Particles position.

My Particle Class looks like this:

```
class Particle: SKShapeNode{
    var pos = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var vel = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    var acc = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    var radius:CGFloat
    var maxSpeed:CGFloat
    var color: SKColor
```

And i have a function which looks like this to show the Particles:

```
func show(){
    self.position = self.pos
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), size: CGSize(width: self.radius*2, height: self.radius*2))
    let bezierP = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    self.path = bezierP.cgPath
    self.fillColor = self.color
    self.strokeColor = .clear
}
```

And in the update function i have this loop:

```
    for particle in partikelArr{
        particle.updatePos()
        particle.show()
    }
```

How could i now "colorize" the white background or "draw" my particle on the background based on the particles position, color, shape and size?

Thanks and best regards

EDIT:
So i know create for each particle a new SKShapeNode inside the update function, so this works and it looks like the Particles have colorized the background:
[image: Working Example]

This was created like this inside the update function:

```
    for particle in partikelArr{
        let newP = SKShapeNode(path: particle.path!)
        newP.position = particle.pos
        newP.fillColor = particle.farbe
        newP.strokeColor = .clear
        newP.zPosition = 1000
        newP.alpha = 0.1
        self.addChild(newP)
    }
```

But i do **not want** to create SKShapeNodes for each Particle (on the screenshot i have used 5 Particles, after some seconds i already have over 800 nodes on the scene). **I would like to let my 100 Particles really "draw" their Shape and Color on the white Background node.**

Comment: I wonder how many particles you can have at max before your app starts lagging ? Keep in mind that one SKShapeNode requires one draw call, which is extremely unperformant. About the problem ... You haven't showed what have you tried and what results you got (maybe some screenshots?) What [blendMode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1519931-blendmode) have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Whirlwind Thank you for your response. I have edited my question. The blendMode is not the issue. I would like to have 100 particles which move around and which colorize the white background Node with their shape and color - so when i say "draw" i really mean that they draw on the background. I do not want to create new Nodes which then do not move, even though this would get me my effect - like you said this would cause bad performance issues. Sorry for my bad english, i hope my question is now more clear and again thank you for your response.

Comment: You should be able to apply shaders that work on individual particles, see the example on this link https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skemitternode

Comment: SpriteKit has its own Particle System. If that is not enough for you, I guess using shaders would be a way to go...

Comment: Almost got it https://youtu.be/_re69_hWvPQ .. but this costs to much perfomance. Wish SpriteKit had a way to simply just draw something without creating an object. Wonder how the p5 library works without any performance issues at this topic.